# How to add email while trying to create a Household contact using civicrm api v3?

Tags: api, households

[image]

I want to add email address to create a contact of type Household , how I can achieve it as while checking in API explorer I don't see it.

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'create', [
  'contact_type' => "Household",
  'household_name' => "Test",
  'email' => 'abc@gmail.com
]];
```

I was trying to convert civicrm API v2 to civicrm API v3.
In civicrm API v2, I saw this, so I thought we may have some way to add email directly in API v3 (also not sure if api v2 below is correct)

```
$householdParams = array(
                    'household_name' => $familyName,
                    'contact_type'   => 'Household',
                    'email'          => $form_state['storage']['contactInfoValues']['emailAddress']
                    );
$householdContact =&civicrm_contact_add($householdParams);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use the Email API with the contact_id of the just created contact. You can do this in a chained API call if you want to.

Comment: See the docs for how to do chaining: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/chaining/

Comment: @JaapJansma-CiviCooP thanks